# Unicycle-like robot simulation

Tags: control, ros, module

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to simulate the behavior of a unicycle under the action of different control laws. Are there any valid and available already made modules for unicycle-like robot simulations? Which one can fit better for this aim?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65154/unicycle-like-robot-simulation/) by [martz](https://answers.ros.org/users/5151/martz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want to ask this on the [gazebo site](http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0